# Need Help Repackaging Modified OBB File for Efootball 24 Mobile on Unreal Engine 4.26.2

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to make a patch for Efootball 24 Mobile, which is made of Unreal Engine 4.26.2. I've extracted the obb file using 7 zip and replaced the texture using Unreal Engine. But I don't know how to repackage it.

I've tried to make it a zip file, then rename it to the.obb extension. But it didn't work.